# Copy existing project into git for version control

Tags: git, version-control, version

Good day people.

Please help me. I'm going to get job in big company where overall uses version management. And I stared to learn git.  I want to copy my project into newly created git repository to start version control. My project structure is:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── demidov
│   │   │   │   └── pkg
│   │   │   │       ├── domain
│   │   │   │       │   ├── ComputerMaintenanceEvent.java
│   │   │   │       │   ├── SoftwareDevelopmentEvent.java
│   │   │   │       │   ├── TheUser.java
│   │   │   │       │   ├── UserContactInfo.java
│   │   │   │       │   └── UserEvents.java
│   │   │   │       ├── persistence
│   │   │   │       │   ├── AppOut.java
│   │   │   │       │   ├── UserSecurityService.java
│   │   │   │       │   ├── WebContentDAOIF.java
│   │   │   │       │   └── WebContentDAOImpl.java
│   │   │   │       ├── service
│   │   │   │       └── web
│   │   │   │           ├── LoginController.java
│   │   │   │           └── RenderSiteController.java
│   │   │   ├── userEvents.hbm.xml
│   │   │   └── user.hbm.xml
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── resources
│   │       │   ├── css
│   │       │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │       │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │       │   │   ├── bootstrap-responsive.css
│   │       │   │   └── bootstrap-responsive.min.css
│   │       │   ├── img
│   │       │   │   ├── background_java.jpg
│   │       │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings.png
│   │       │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
│   │       │   └── js
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.js
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │       │       ├── jquery-1.10.2.min.js
│   │       │       ├── jquery.nav.js
│   │       │       └── jquery.scrollTo.js
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           ├── spring
│   │           │   ├── security-context.xml
│   │           │   ├── servletConfig
│   │           │   │   └── servlet-context.xml
│   │           │   └── spring-context.xml
│   │           ├── view
│   │           │   ├── home.jsp
│   │           │   └── login.jsp
│   │           └── web.xml
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── demidov
    │   │   └── pkg
    │   │       ├── domain
    │   │       │   ├── ComputerMaintenanceEvent.class
    │   │       │   ├── SoftwareDevelopmentEvent.class
    │   │       │   ├── TheUser.class
    │   │       │   ├── UserContactInfo.class
    │   │       │   └── UserEvents.class
    │   │       ├── persistence
    │   │       │   ├── AppOut.class
    │   │       │   ├── UserSecurityService.class
    │   │       │   ├── WebContentDAOIF.class
    │   │       │   └── WebContentDAOImpl.class
    │   │       ├── service
    │   │       └── web
    │   │           ├── LoginController.class
    │   │           └── RenderSiteController.class
    │   ├── userEvents.hbm.xml
    │   └── user.hbm.xml
    ├── m2e-wtp
    │   └── web-resources
    │       └── META-INF
    │           ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │           └── maven
    │               └── demidov.pkg
    │                   └── webcontent
    │                       ├── pom.properties
    │                       └── pom.xml
    └── test-classes
```

How can I add it into git to start my version management??
Thank you with best regards.

Comment: Why does your project structure matters ? I mean what do you want to achieve with git in relation to your project ? Is `git init && git add .`  not enough ? You can refer to http://git-scm.com/book as for how to start with git.

Comment: I hope so. Since I just started to learn git a couple hours ago and tried git add, but from documentation from git.scm.com it copies each file saperatly, I want to copy whole my structure by one command to git repository. and I do: git add /home/vadim/Desktop/webcontent/* where webcontent is folder where my projects laing down and by * I mean copy all inside webcontent. After I get /home/vadim/Desktop/webcontent/pom.xml' is outside repository. What is the problem??

Comment: Try `git add -A` from the project root to add all the files in the current directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: It says: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Before this  I create git directory and did git init. It says: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vadim/Documents/git/.git/

Answer (score 0):

From the root of your personal project, did you run `git init` and then `git add .`?